# Creating a heatmap from TIFF file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, smoothing

The task which I am currently working on, has us to create a kind of a 'heatmap' with KDE (or similar).

[image: Input TIFF file]

As a first step I vectorized the TIFF File and now it looks like this:
[image: Zoomed in vectorized data]

The end product should look something like a heatmap (ie. not chopped up like it currently is).

Is this possible in QGIS? Or is there a Python code/library I could use that does the trick?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Using "Raster Pixel to Point" and then using 'Heatmap (kernel density estimation)' would probably be more direct than handling polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the vectorized layer you created is a polygon layer with an attribute you use to create the color range. Convert the polygons to points using `menu processing / toolbox / geometry by expression` and, define output as points and set the expression to `centroid ($geometry)`.

It will create a new points layer with points in the middle of your cells (pixels) with the same attributes as in the polygons. Now you can use Heatmap as rendering style in the symbology.

See my grid with randomly created values and the dialog window for geometry by expression:

[image]

This is how the create the heatmap:

[image]